# Mouse coordinates relative to currentTarget in React in event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an outer div which catches `onWheel` mouse events. In the handler I would like to know the mouse pointer coordinates *relative to the outer div*. For example:

```
constructor() {
  this.handleWheel = this.handleWheel.bind(this);
}

handleWheel(event) {
  // how do I get mouse position relative to the outer div here?
}

render() {
  return (
    <div onWheel={this.handleWheel}>
      ...
      <img src="..." />
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I move mouse pointer over the image and scroll mousewheel, `event.target` is set to `<img>` and `event.currentTarget` is set to `<div>`. I can also get the mouse position relative to `event.target` (`event.nativeEvent.offsetX/Y`), but that doesn't help me because I don't know the position of `<img>` relative to `<div>`.

In other words, I'm stuck... How do I get the mouse position relative to the element that has a handler attached?

Answer (score 21):

I have found a solution which works and am posting it here if it helps someone. I'm not sure though if it is the best one, so I would appreciate some comments (and possibly better solutions).

```
handleWheel(event) {
  let currentTargetRect = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
  const event_offsetX = event.pageX - currentTargetRect.left,
        event_offsetY = event.pageY - currentTargetRect.top;
  //...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm, was looking at how to use getBoundingClientRect from the even and here it is :)

Comment: Good solution. In my case I needed to account for the page scroll position as well. For anyone else in this boat: `event_offsetY = event.pageY - window.pageYOffset - currentTargetRect.top`.